# LR CC and Wacom Bamboo tablet - performance issues

Tags: lightroom

Environment is Lightroom CC (latest version) on Win7Pro x64, 16GB, NVIDIA GTX750Ti.

I use a Bamboo Fun tablet (CTH-661/S), with the most current drivers, which works quite well in general, with one exception.  When using certain tools that require a click+drag action, LR bogs down and becomes unresponsive while the pen is down.  By "bog down" I mean that the display stops updating completely during the drag, and takes several seconds to catch up.  CPU goes to 100% on one core.  The same operation executed with the mouse exhibits no slowdown.

Typical operations that bog down include

- Dragging the graduated filter during initial placement to set the width or orientation
- Changing the width or orientation of an existing graduated filter
- Dragging the *source* area of a spot removal
- Dragging the *target* of spot removal is slow but more usable
- Placing the lines for guided perspective correction

For all of the above operations the tablet is essentially useless. I have to use the mouse.  Also, the problem is the same regardless of whether or not I have "Use Graphics Processor" enabled.

In contrast, some click+drag operations *don't* cause a slowdown at all:

- Dragging in the crop overlay tool:  resizing crop and panning under the crop border, drawing vertical/horizontal correction line
- Panning the image with the hand tool when zoomed in
- Painting with the adjustment brush
- Scrolling (any sub-window)
- Dragging adjustment sliders in Develop mode

Has anyone experienced this with any Wacom tablet, and is there some configuration or driver setting that fixes the problem?

Comment: I have a wacom CTH661S(A) too. I use lightroom also, however I don't have the CC version. I use LR4. I have not experienced what you're experiencing. However, if it helps in anyway, I have trouble tapping with the pen in VLC. I have to tap many times to get the play button to work!. Meanwhile, if I use the tablet hardbuttons it works fine. Maybe try using your dragging operations with the tablet left-click button when you start your drag; and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: "Latest Version" isn't really a version. Since this question is 2 years old, the "latest version" now is probably quite different. Specifying a particular version would be much more helpful for someone who happened to run into the same or similar problem.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with Wacom Bamboo CTL-470K and Lightroom 6.12 standalone/perpetual (Win7x64, i7-3520M, 16GB, Intel HD4000). I was able to narrow down the issue somewhat: the slowdown seems to be related to the pen "keypress". If I use the pen to move the mouse, but press the left mouse button using the button on my laptop, there is no "bog down" and everything works pretty snappy. Doubt this info would help, but who knows. My Wacom drivers are v.5.3.5 (or 5.3.5-3, not sure about the correct naming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the problem was, it seems to have been fixed by the latest release, Lightroom CC Classic 7.2, so the problem must have been in Lightroom all along.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Windows Ink deactivated and that you have the latest Wacom drivers.

(Wacom drivers don't shine by their reliability; I have reoccurring problems with them)

Comment: The OP uses Win7 and Windows Ink is a feature of Windows 10 only. The latest Windows drivers version for Bamboo Create, Capture, Connect, Splash, as well as earlier Bamboo CTL and CTH models is 5.3.5-3 released on 8/20/2015. Wacom have not updated it ever since and possibly never will at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable lens corrections while painting and using gradient filters. This can cause lightroom to become a bit sluggish.

Comment: How would that affect the tablet but not the mouse?

Comment: My fault. Didn't read the question right.Then it probably is a driver issue from your tablet. Maybe you can try an older version of the drivers?

Comment: I've tried old versions and new versions, and Wacom claims it's not their problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison so you have contacted Wacom about the issue?

Comment: Twice, they disavow all responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all tablet on screen animations or see if you experience the same issues with Capture One.